# Escaping plus in sed regular expression

Tags: regex, ubuntu, sed, escaping, posix

There is a file with following text:

```
CXX_FLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-braces -ffloat-store -pthread -std=gnu++17
```

To replace the string "-std=gnu++17" with "-std=c++17 -std=gnu++17", I tried:

```
sed -i -e 's/\-std\=gnu\+\+17/\-std=c\+\+17 \-std=gnu\+\+17/g' filename
```

That however does not work, until I remove the \ escape from frst + sign in search expression. So these seem to be OK:

```
sed -i -e 's/\-std\=gnu++17/\-std=c\+\+17 \-std=gnu\+\+17/g' filename
sed -i -e 's/\-std\=gnu+\+17/\-std=c\+\+17 \-std=gnu\+\+17/g' filename
sed -i -e 's/\-std\=gnu..17/\-std=c\+\+17 \-std=gnu\+\+17/g' filename
```

I understand the + *must* be escaped when not in character class, but I thought one can prefix any character with backslash in regex. Why does escaping the + sign here cause the search-replace to fail?

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: wrt `I understand the + must be escaped when not in character class` - no, it doesn't in a BRE. wrt `I thought one can prefix any character with backslash in regex` - no, one can't as doing so can turn a literal char into a meta-char. See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for which chars can/must be escaped and how each has to be handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not used `-r` nor `-E` option, so you tell `sed` to parse the regex pattern as a POSIX BRE expression. In GNU `sed`, in a POSIX BRE expression, `\+` is a quantifier matching 1 or more occurrences of the quantified pattern. Run `sed -e 's/\-std\=gnu\+\+17/\-std=c\+\+17 \-std=gnu\+\+17/g' <<< '-std=gnuuuu17'` and the result will be `-std=c++17 -std=gnu++17`. To match `+`, you just need to use `+`.

Note you overescaped a lot of chars and your command is unnecessarily long because you repeated the pattern in both the LHS and RHS.

You may use the following POSIX BRE `sed` command with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/-std=gnu++17/-std=c++17 &/' filename
```

See the [`sed` online demo](https://ideone.com/qZOJoc):

```
s='CXX_FLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-braces -ffloat-store -pthread -std=gnu++17'
sed 's/-std=gnu++17/-std=c++17 &/' <<< "$s"
# => CXX_FLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-braces -ffloat-store -pthread -std=c++17 -std=gnu++17
```

**Details**

- `-std=gnu++17` - the string pattern matches `-std=gnu++17` string exactly
- `-std=c++17 &` - the replacement pattern is `-std=c++17`, space and `&` stands for the whole match, `-std=gnu++17`.

Comment: OK, BRE acknowledged, was thinking it is all just regex. And thanks for more compact expression!

Comment: Good answer, well explained ++